# How to Include a reference to a table in Invantive Excel add-in

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-control

I'm making a financial report in Excel using the data from Exact Online using the Invantive Control Excel Add-in. In Exact Online I have a classification for the General Ledgers. In my Excel file, I would like to match these classifications on my reporting schedule. Therefore, I made a table with a mapping of the Exact Online classifications and the reporting classifications. 
Using the Invantive Control Excel add-in, I entered the following SQL query:

```
    select periods_year_reportingyear_attr
,      reportingperiod_attr
,      division_code
,      division_hid
,      division_name
,      periods_year_years_balance_code_attr
,      periods_year_years_balance_description
,      '=I_EOL_GL_ACTCLN_CODE($C{E,.,.,^+2,.}, $C{E,.,.,^+5,.})' verdichting_code
,      '=I_EOL_GL_ACTCLN_DESCRIPTION($C{E,.,.,^+2,.}, $C{E,.,.,^+5,.})' verdichting_naam
,      '=i_eol_bal_year_open($C{E,.,.,^+2,.} , $C{E,.,.,^,.}, $C{E,.,.,^+5,.}) + if($C{E,.,.,^+1,.} = 1, 0, i_eol_bal_pder($C{E,.,.,^+2,.},$C{E,.,.,^,.},1,$C{E,.,.,^+1,.}-1,$C{E,.,.,^+5,.}))' startsaldo
,      balance
,      '=i_eol_bal_year_open($C{E,.,.,^+2,.} , $C{E,.,.,^,.}, $C{E,.,.,^+5,.}) + i_eol_bal_pder($C{E,.,.,^+2,.},$C{E,.,.,^,.},1,$C{E,.,.,^+1,.},$C{E,.,.,^+5,.})' eindsaldo
,      periods_year_years_balance_balancetype_attr
,      '=INDEX(tab_reporting[Reporting],MATCH(NUMBERVALUE(I_EOL_GL_ACTCLN_CODE($C{E,.,.,^+2,.}, $C{E,.,.,^+5,.})),tab_reporting[GL Class - Code],0))' reporting
from   balancelinesperperiod 
order 
by     periods_year_reportingyear_attr
,      reportingperiod_attr
,      division_hid
,      periods_year_years_balance_code_attr
```

In which tab_reporting is the name of a table with de mapping of the reporting classifications and the Exact Online. This table is on a different tab within Excel. When I review the data I will see these results:
[image]
Which, to me looks oke.

One thing that I don't understand is that it looks like there are 4 fields on position 14. The one formula appears to create 4 different data fields in stead of one.

[image]

I could send the Excel file upon request. 
The problem is that I end up with this error message:

> itgensdf031: Kan velden van blok 'Balans (bal)' niet verversen. Can
>   not refresh fields completely. The field '});TAB_REPORTING[GL CLASS -
>   CODE];0))'' has a Formule which will get lost when the field is
>   deleted since it no longer occurs in the SQL.
>
> Migrate all relevant field settings that you need to keep and would
>   get lost when this field is removed. Hire a consultant if you don't
>   know how to do this.
>
> Type: Invantive.Data.ValidationException    at
>   Invantive.Data.ValidationException..ctor(String messageCode, String
>   messageText, String kindRequest, String localStackTrace, String nk,
>   Exception innerException)    at
>   Invantive.Producer.Control.Utility.RefreshFields(ModelCache
>   modelCache, iea_blocks_v block, Boolean allowLoadFromCache)    at
>   Invantive.Producer.Control.SyncToDatabaseForm.syncBackGroundWorker_DoWork(Object
>   sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
>   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object
>   argument)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(Object
>   o)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()    at
>   Invantive.Producer.Control.Utility.RefreshFields(ModelCache
>   modelCache, iea_blocks_v block, Boolean allowLoadFromCache) in
>   File173:line 4362    at
>   Invantive.Producer.Control.SyncToDatabaseForm.syncBackGroundWorker_DoWork(Object
>   sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in File174:line 299 Type:
>   Invantive.Data.ValidationException    at
>   Invantive.Data.ValidationException..ctor(String messageCode, String
>   messageText, String kindRequest, String localStackTrace, String nk,
>   Exception innerException)    at
>   Invantive.Producer.Control.SyncToDatabaseForm.syncBackGroundWorker_DoWork(Object
>   sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
>   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object
>   argument)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(Object
>   o)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
>
> Invantive Control for Excel (stable-20161021-2025-ge3e5e61 Prod,
>   L162135034)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have managed through a bug somewhere to create multiple fields at position 14. This is a corruption of the repository.

I recommend to first remove the fields at position 14 by:

- unchecking their properties
- remove the part from the SQL that defines the fields at position 14 (save it somewhere),
- and then pressing Refresh in the fields tab.

Check that the fields at position 14 are gone.

The re-add the part from the SQL that defines the fields at position 14.

It should work again.